# document.querySelect em body

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, array

Como utilizar a sessão de código `document.querySelector` para alterar/mudar a imagem de fundo de uma página `<body>...</body>`

Ex:

```
var imagem_lista = [
    "http://static.gamespot.com/uploads/original/1179/11799911/2324138-warface11.jpg",
    "http://glasshome.tv/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/Warface_Screenshot019_Climb.jpg",
    "http://hq.warface.com/updates/endless-skies/img/WF_ES_019.jpg",
    "http://lodik.ru/uploads/posts/2015-02/1423304948_warface-3.jpg",
    "http://hq.warface.com/updates/siberia/img/wf-update-coldpeak-03.jpg",
    "http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/warface/images/4/43/Warface_WeapCustom_Combat_201.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20130301001625"
];

window.onload=function(){
    var url_pagina = window.location.href;
    if(!url_pagina.indexOf('/p/')){
        var numero_aleatorio = random_number(0, imagem_lista.lenght);
        mudar_imagem(imagem_lista[numero_aleatorio]);
    }
}

function random_number(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function mudar_imagem(image){

  // usar este 
    document.querySelector('body').style.background-image=image;
  // ou este
    $('body').css('background-image', 'url(' + image + ')');
}
```

E um dos error é o seguinte:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment`

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: imagem_lista is not defined
    at :2:7
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn (:905:140)
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap (:838:34)
    at Object.InjectedScript.evaluate (:694:21)
```

OBS: O Arquivo que contém o script está hospedado em:

http://brasilr2.net76.net/js/webmaster.body.js

*Na linha: indexOf*

Eu quero identificar quando um usuário acessa meu blog para mudar o fundo da imagem de acordo com um tema definido.

Ex: A home do blog está definida para com uma dessas imagens em `imagem_lista`.
(**http://warfeicebrasil.blogspot.com.br**)

Agora por exemplo na página de modo sobrevivencia do jogo citado lá, o tema deve mudar logo o fundo também. (**http://warfeicebrasil.blogspot.com.br/p/operacao-cold-peak.html**)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problema com os hifens

Isto está **errado**:

```
document.querySelector('body').style.background-image=image;
```

Note que o erro

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

É causado pelo uso de `.background-image`

*Hifens* são usados para operações no javascript e faltou o `url(...)`, pra setar o `background-image` você deve fazer assim:

```
document.querySelector('body').style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + image + ')';
```

Note que `backgroundImage` usa o `I` em maiusculo, se fosse font-size, ficaria o S em maiusculo:

```
document.querySelector('body').style.fontSize
```

Então para cada hifen a proxima letra é em maiusculo, esta regra só não se aplica aos prefixos `-webkit`, `-moz` e `-o`, por exemplo `-webkit-filter` deve ficar assim:

```
document.querySelector('body').style.webkitFilter
```

No entanto se você está usando jquery (o que parece o caso), então aplique com:

```
$('body').css('background-image', 'url(' + image + ')');
```

---

### Outros erros

Outro problema é que você escreveu `imagem_lista.lenght`, mas `lenght` não existe o correto é `length`.

---

### Problema com o indexOf

`indexOf` não é retorna dados do tipo `true` ou `false`

- Ele retorna de 0 ou mais para quando encontrar a string
- Retorna -1 quando não encontrar

Então o correto seria:

```
//Se não tiver /p/ na url
if(-1 === url_pagina.indexOf('/p/')){
    var numero_aleatorio = random_number(0, imagem_lista.length);
    mudar_imagem(imagem_lista[numero_aleatorio]);
}
```

Se quiser que ele troque o background quando encontrar `/p/` na url use assim:

```
//Se tiver /p/ na url
if(-1 !== url_pagina.indexOf('/p/')){
    var numero_aleatorio = random_number(0, imagem_lista.length);
    mudar_imagem(imagem_lista[numero_aleatorio]);
}
```

Comment: Ok sua resposta foi muito válida mas quando eu entro na home do site ele ainda não muda com base no script: brasilr2.net76.net/js/webmaster.body.js

Comment: Na home deve-se alterar o fundo por qualquer imagem pelo array do __image_lista__

Comment: Ok lhe aguardo...

Comment: funcionou se eu invocar o metodo mudar_imagem

Comment: mas fora isso aparece isso __GET http://warfeicebrasil.blogspot.com.br/undefined 404 (Not Found)__

Comment: se eu apertar F12 e invocar o metodo acontede, mas fora disso GET http://warfeicebrasil.blogspot.com.br/undefined 404 (Not Found)

Comment: esta indicando a linha 24 do arquivo que da a exceção:

document.querySelector('body').style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + image + ')';

Comment: @Nathan1302 Achei o problema e atualizei a resposta :)

Comment: realmente agora funcionou! eu sempre me confundo com __lenght__ e __length__

Comment: @Nathan1302 eu também, vivo me confundindo, um que eu confundia muito era `keyCode` e `keycode`, na verdade o `C` é maiúsculo, mas eu as vezes esqueço :) é normal

Comment: : } obridago! e deixa eu pergunta na lista ex: tem 4 itens o length vai ser de 0, 1, 2, 3 não 1, 2, 3, 4. eu posso aplicar -1 no length?

Comment: @Nathan1302 tá certo é isto mesmo, esqueci de ver este detalhe :)